# There are 5 accounts. I need to pay a bill of $3,000, but I need take money out of these accounts relatively.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There are $5$ accounts:

1. has $\$1,881.40$,
2. has $\$ 1,662.80$,
3. has $\$461.40$,
4. has $\$ 381.40$
5. has  $\$ 180$.

I need to pay a bill of $\$3,000$, but I need to take money out of these accounts and pay this bill relatively. That is, the account with more $ will pay the biggest share and the account with less will pay the lowest share. How do I do this calculation?

Thank you

Comment: Let $m$ be some amount of money. What you take from account #1 will be $1881.40 m$; from account #2: $1662.80 m$; etc. Then what?

Answer (score 1):

Total \$ across all 5 accounts = \$4,567. \$3,000 as percent of total \$: 3,000 / 4,567 $\approx$ .65%. So you need about 65% of each account.

Edit to address your clarification.

So you have 7 people. The dollar value for their accounts is $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$, $F$, $G$. The total dollar value is $A + B + C + D + E + F + G = X$. Then the percent of the \$3,000 person $A$ will pay is $\frac{A}{X}$. So $A$ pays $\frac{A}{X} \times 3000$. Do the same for each other person as well.

Comment: See the problem I am having: This is a network marketing company, and we opened 7 accounts to 7 different people (1 on the top, 2 in the middle, and 4 at the bottom - like a triangle), so, the account on the top will always make more money than the ones at the bottom. Our purpose is to finance other peoples' accounts with the money we're getting paid from the MLM company, however, the person at the top has to pay a larger share than the people at the bottom. It has to be proportional in this way. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorScardua Please see my edit. Welcome to math.stackexchange! Please remember to vote up helpful answers, and to mark an answer as accepted if it answers your question. This will increase your reputation on the site and give you more privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Let us call $A,B,C,D,E$ the amount on each account. If I rpoperly understand, you want to take from each account the same proportion, say $x$. So, from the first account, you will take $x A$, from the second $x B$ and so on. If you add all of these, you will take $$ x(A+B+C+D+E)$$ and you want that this be equal to 3000. So, $$x(A+B+C+D+E)=3000$$ gives you an equation to be solved for $x$. When you have the value of $x$, just go backward and compute $xA$, $xB$ and so on.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: See the problem I am having: This is a network marketing company, and we opened 7 accounts to 7 different people (1 on the top, 2 in the middle, and 4 at the bottom - like a triangle), so, the account on the top will always make more money than the ones at the bottom. Our purpose is to finance other peoples' accounts with the money we're getting paid from the MLM company, however, the person at the top has to pay a larger share than the people at the bottom. It has to be proportional in this way. Thank you.

Comment: @IgorScardua. You are welcome.